# Why doesn't finally block execute in a custom scheduler?

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduler

I am writing a custom bounded scheduler. This should be able to schedule tasks with a given delay. Try to schedule tasks if the bound has been reached, throwing an exception after a timeout. Here is what I have so far:

```java
public class BoundedScheduledExecutor {

  private final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor;
  private final Semaphore semaphore;
  private final int maxWaitSeconds;

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
    BoundedScheduledExecutor.class
  );

  // constructor omitted

  public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable task, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
    throws Exception {
    try {
      boolean result = semaphore.tryAcquire(this.maxWaitSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      LOG.info("result {}", result);
      LOG.info("executor {}", this.executor.getActiveCount());
      LOG.info("semaphore {}", this.semaphore);
      if (result) {
        return this.executor.schedule(
            () -> {
              try {
                LOG.info("before run");
                task.run();
              } finally {
                semaphore.release();
              }
            },
            delay,
            unit
          );
      } else {
        semaphore.release();
        throw new RejectedExecutionException();
      }
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
      semaphore.release();
      throw e;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

The code is based on a similar implementation from Java concurrency in practice. In my test, I am trying to verify that if I have a short task and another task following that, the second one is scheduled once the short task finishes. My test is this:

```java
  public void itSchedulesAfterTimeoutWhenQueueIsFull() throws Exception {
    this.boundedScheduledExecutor = new BoundedScheduledExecutor(executor, 1, 3);
    Runnable blockingTask = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
      }
    };

    Runnable simpleTask = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {}
    };

    this.boundedScheduledExecutor.schedule(blockingTask, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    this.boundedScheduledExecutor.schedule(simpleTask, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
```

But the second call to `schedule` throws an exception because `tryAcquire` returns false. I expect my test should succeed because the first task takes 1s and is scheduled right away. The second one is scheduled after 5s, I was expecting the semaphore will be released in between so that the second task can proceed. I noticed that the semaphore is not released in the `finally` block for the scheduled task. How do I get the semaphore to release after a task is complete? Why doesn't the finally block execute?

Comment: Typically the only thing that would cause a `finally` to not run is either the JVM exiting or the thread it is running on being interrupted/killed, but the latter is a fairly severe circumstance (without any checks for `Thread#isInterrupted`). How are you confirming it isn't running the `finally`, other than the semaphore not being released?

Comment: I am not confirming in any other way. My final goal is to get the semaphore to release after the task is complete.

Comment: Honestly your semaphore may just not be released. I would first confirm what is running when (either through a debugger or a print statement, since threading can be a little funky with a debugger).

Comment: third reason for `finally` not running, the `try` is not being executed/started

Comment: True enough (and likely the case here): if you don't run it, it won't run.

Comment: Your actual question has been answered already, but you should further note that when `tryAcquire` returns `false` you *must not* call `release()` as you didn’t acquire the semaphore. But you’re doing exactly that, before throwing a `RejectedExecutionException`, then adding fuel to the flames by catching your own `RejectedExecutionException` and calling `release()` a second time before rethrowing the exception.

Answer (score 2):

```
return this.executor.schedule(
   () -> {
      try {
         LOG.info("before run");
         task.run();
      } finally {
         semaphore.release();
      }
    },
    delay,
    unit
    );
```

This code does not execute the lambda, it just sends it to the executor that will execute it at some time.

Even if the executor starts running the lambda as soon as it receives it, your main code will not wait for it and the `return` will be applied, even if the lambda is still running the task.

So it may very well be that the first scheduled task still has not been able to release the semaphore before you invoke this method again, unless you are adding additional controls outside of this code.

In fact with your code you cannot have more than one task scheduled at a given time; until the task currently scheduled has not being finished you will not release the semaphor, but you require acquiring it to schedule a new task.

Comment: That matches my expectation. But then my test should succeed, because the first task takes 1s and is scheduled right away. The second one is scheduled after 5s, I was expecting the semaphore will be released in between so that the second task can proceed.

Comment: It's scheduled (aka queued) immediately, but not necessarily _executed_ right away. The scheduler has its own separate thread which will pick it up when it does.

Comment: If by *The second one is scheduled after 5s* you mean *I pass a value of 5000 at the delay parameter*, you got it wrong. You are trying to acquire the semaphore **before** trying to schedule the task, so it does not matter the value of *delay*. Those 5 seconds of difference would have to be between invocations to your *schedule* method (and of course, there is no guarantee that the scheduled task will have ended by then, although it may be a reasonable supposition).